# red5 play video oflademo using actionscript

Tags: actionscript, record, red5, playback

Hello i have the following problem,
I record a video using red5 like this:

```
nc = new NetConnection();
nc.connect("rtmp://localhost/oflaDemo");
ns = new NetStream(nc); 
ns.attachCamera(cam);
ns.attachAudio(mic);
ns.publish( "file1", "record" );
```

and the video is stored in
C:\Program Files (x86)\Red5\webapps\oflaDemo\streams

while when i try to play the same video i do:

```
nc = new NetConnection();
nc.connect(null);
ns = new NetStream(nc);
ns.client = nsClient;
video = new Video(myVid.width,myVid.height);
video.attachNetStream(ns);
video.smoothing=true;
myVid.addChild(video);
ns.play("http://localhost:5080/oflaDemo/file1.flv");
```

but it throws Error #2044: Unhandled NetStatusEvent:. level=error, code=NetStream.Play.StreamNotFound

any ideas???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem on how to play the video with:

```
<s:VideoPlayer id="myVid" visible="true" width="100%" height="100%" mediaPlayerStateChange="myVid_mediaPlayerStateChangeHandler(event)">
 <s:source>
   <s:DynamicStreamingVideoSource host="{mediaServerUrl}" streamType="recorded">
      <s:DynamicStreamingVideoItem streamName="{videoFolder}/{filename}"/>
   </s:DynamicStreamingVideoSource>
 </s:source>
</s:VideoPlayer>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please change **ns.play("http://localhost:5080/oflaDemo/file1.flv");**  to **ns.play("rtmp://localhost:5080/oflaDemo/file1.flv");** hope it useful with you

Comment: rtmp port is not 5080 by default! it should be 1935, so: ns.play("rtmp://localhost:1935/oflaDemo/file1.flv"); or simply ns.play("rtmp://localhost/oflaDemo/file1.flv");